# How does the Paris Disneyland Fastpass system work?

Tags: tickets, paris, disney

I am planning a visit to the Paris Disneyland which is notorious for having huge lines. I've read that there is a 'Fastpass' system, but it's a bit hard to understand how it works. So here are my questions:

1. How can I obtain a Fastpass ticket?
2. Can I receive a discount for reserving one in advance?
3. Are there levels of Fastpass tickets? Some websites mention a 'VIP' Fastpass.
4. Are there other options of quickly skipping the queues?

For the sake of the question I'm only interested in the 'thrill' rides, so it's okay if a certain ticket doesn't skip queues to the restaurants or the child rides.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.disneylandparis.co.uk/guest-services/fast-pass/ ?

Comment: @RvdK yes, but it seemed a bit vague to me. Specifically it wasn't clear how to buy the 'VIP' ticket

Comment: indeed a bit hidden but available on the page: You need to stay at a hotel of Disneyland Paris. "As a Suites or Castle Club Guest, you'll board within a matter of minutes to the attractions that offer the FASTPASS® service (only available at Disneyland® Hotel, Disney's Hotel New York®, Disney's Newport Bay Club® and Disney's Sequoia Lodge®)."

Comment: It's true that if you stay at the hotel literally over the gate, and indeed have a suite or whatever, you can avoid (most) queues. However it is just absurdly overpriced, unfortunately.  Other than that, just forget it, the fastpass system etc is of little/no help.  (the true "insider's" fastpass system is only for celebs, corporate vips, etc, forget it)

Comment: I alert you that *the actual joy* of Disneyland is the 2-3 hours of *waiting in line* for each ride. (The rides themselves are of no consequence.) It's a rare, almost unique, family time. The kids are ecstatic (as if before xmas) and they know that it's finally the parents doing something just for them. It's typically the one and only time in a kid's life that the parents, very explicitly, give so much time for them. That's the inner psychology of the experience. Enjoy!!

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm sure you're right but... I'm planning on going alone and I don't in fact have kids :)

Comment: I see. In that case you will hate the lines!  You'll just have to zen in to it.  the FP is stupid, it does nothing, unfortunately just forget it.  the Hôtel l'Élysée Val d'Europe (if you get a good rate) is a very practical choice; the Ibis(s) nearby are also OK. A tremendous tip is, assuming you have a car just drive (I mean the couple miles) from the hotel to park at the park; the free busses are fine but it's an incredible pain when you have to wait for one and you catch the schedule wrong. it's just tremendously easier if you have your car at hand; of course it costs a couple $. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FASTPASS and Disneyland Paris works the same way as Disneyland.

1. There are FASTPASS Distribution machines near the entrance to FP attractions.  You insert your park pass to obtain the FP 'ticket'.
2. Discounts are not in any way part of FPs at any Disney park. :(
3. No, not generally.  There are various super FP that are given to VIP's or as compensation for guest experience issues.  They resemble the old tickets at Walt Disney World.
4. There are two additional ways:

   - Several attractions have Single Rider queues.  I can tell you though, the SR queue for Crush's Coaster takes just as long as the regular line.
   - If you are staying at a Disney Hotel, you can enter the parks early during Extra Magic Hours.

Details on Disneyland Paris FASTPASS: [Disneyland® Paris FASTPASS®](http://www.disneylandparis.co.uk/guest-services/fast-pass/)

Details on Single Rider attractions: [Disneyland® Paris SINGLE RIDER](http://www.disneylandparis.com/en-us/guest-services/single-rider-service/)

The Walt Disney World Resort uses a completely different FP system.